# Cannot read properties of undefined with react-chartjs-2 and chart js problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

When I want to use react chartjs it is giving me these errors

[image]

The version I use for chart.js is **^3.5.0** and **^4.0.1** for react-chartjs-2

I downgrade it to version 2 but it didn't work

**Chart component codes**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'
import { Chart as ChartJS } from 'chart.js/auto'

function Chart({ chartData }) {
    return <Bar data={chartData} />
}

export default Chart
```

**Main component**

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
        labels: UserData.map((data) => data.year),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Users Gained',
                data: UserData.map((data) => data.userGain),
            },
        ],
    })
<Chart chartData={data} />
```

**Data**

```
export const UserData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        year: 2016,
        userGain: 80000,
        userLost: 823,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        year: 2017,
        userGain: 45677,
        userLost: 345,
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        year: 2018,
        userGain: 78888,
        userLost: 555,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        year: 2019,
        userGain: 90000,
        userLost: 4555,
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        year: 2020,
        userGain: 4300,
        userLost: 234,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Main component:

```
import { UserData } from './UserData.js';
import React from 'react'

const [data, setData] = React.useState({
        labels: UserData?.map((data) => data.year),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Users Gained',
                data: UserData?.map((data) => data.userGain),
            },
        ],
    })
<Chart chartData={data} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the way you import/read the `UserData`. Assuming the data is defined in `UserData.js`, you could import it as follows:

```
import { UserData } from './UserData.js';
```

Please take a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-chartjs-2-bar?file=index.js) and see how it could work with your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer . i am importing like this there is not another way of imporing

Comment: this error is so annoying :(

Comment: Hi @siamak alipour ,Please try the way I said